# Docker container without isolation? For host system information collecting

Tags: docker

I was trying to do some sysinfo collecting with docker.

As all of our apps run in container, I have to run the detecting script inside a container.

I've already figure out that start a temp container through Docker api and set `privileged=True`, `--pid=host` and `--net=host` can make it access the real host's process and network. By using dmidecode I can collect some of the baseboard information.

Yet there are still some information I can't access, such as DNS settings, python version.

Can I just mount the `/` to the container?

Or find it's there a way to run it with Docker but without any isolation?

Comment: Could you run your script with a `docker exec`? (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: @VonC `The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container`. Still isolated.